# create NSMutableArray for store image from url in tableview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, nsmutablearray

I want store 4 image of book from url (.php?**p=1**&**b=1** display first image of first book) in array and run that code and use these images in tableview.

also I want create any cell in tableview and dedicate first image to first cell (second image to second cell and etc)

this is my code:

```
#import "CarTableViewController.h"
#import "CarTableViewCell.h"

@implementation CarTableViewController
{
    NSData *b;
}
@synthesize carImages;
@synthesize carModels; 
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *numberbook =[[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.101/mamal/book.php?all"]];

    NSInteger numbook = [numberbook integerValue];

    NSString *a;

    for (int i = 1; i <=numbook; i++) {
        a = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.101/mamal/book.php?info=1&b=%d",i]]];
        NSLog(@"%@",a); //names of book

        if(!carModels){
            carModels = [NSMutableArray array];
        }
        [carModels addObject:a];

        b = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.101/mamal/book.php?p=1&b=%d",i]]];
        NSLog(@"%@",b);
        if (!carImages) {
            carImages = [NSMutableArray array];
        }
        [carImages addObject:b];
    }
}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [carModels count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"carTableCell";
    CarTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CarTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.modelLable.text = [carModels objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    UIImage *carPhoto = [UIImage imageWithData:b];
    cell.carImage.image = carPhoto;

    return cell;
}
```

but when run this code simulator display 4 cell in tableview that has 4 different name (correct! I want this) and last image for any cell!!!!???? XD

Answer (score 0):

Your instance variable `b` which holds the image data is overwritten each time a new image is loaded, so the last one loaded is the one whose data is in there.

```
b = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.101/mamal/book.php?p=1&b=%d",i]]];
NSLog(@"%@",b);
if (!carImages) {
    carImages = [NSMutableArray array];
}
[carImages addObject:b];
```

When configuring your cell, you set the image to this data, instead of accessing the `carImages` array.

Do it just like you are doing with the `carModels`:
    cell.modelLable.text = [carModels objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

```
UIImage *carPhoto = [UIImage imageWithData:[carImages objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
cell.carImage.image = carPhoto;
```

Two improvement suggestions, if I may:

1. Make `b` a local variable. No need to have it as an instance variable. You see already that this might cause confusion and therefore lead to bugs.
2. Create the `UIImage` right after loading the data and put that image into the `carImages` array. That way you only have to parse the data for each image once, and not every time the cell is displayed.

   ```
   // ...
   NSData* b = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.101/mamal/book.php?p=1&b=%d",i]]];
   NSLog(@"%@",b);
   if (!carImages) {
       carImages = [NSMutableArray array];
   }
   UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:b];
   [carImages addObject:img];
   //...
   ```

   Then later, when configuring the cell, you can just do

   ```
   cell.carImage.image = [carImages objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
   ```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're reusing the same `NSData *b` variable for all your cells (and hence they show the latest state of b, which is the last image)

Do the following change

instead of

```
UIImage *carPhoto = [UIImage imageWithData:b];
```

do

```
UIImage *carPhoto = [[UIImage imageWithData:[carImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```